# req.body returning undefined when sending data as form-data

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongodb, express

When I'm sending data in my Node.js application as raw JSON/x-www-form-urlencoded from postman it's getting passed but when sending the data as form-data from postman or from my angular frontend, `req.body` is coming as undefined. I'm using `body-parser` on my index.js of my Node.js application.

```
app.post(`${baseUrl}/post-news`, (req, res) => {
  CategoryModel.findOne(
    { categoryId: req.body.category },
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error at finding category ::", err);
        res.send(err);
      }
      if (result) {
        let newArticle = new ArticleModel({
          categoryName: result.categoryName,
          categoryId: result.categoryId,
          imagePath: req.file && req.file.path
        });
        newArticle.save((err, result) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log("Error at saving new news ::", err);
            res.send(err);
          } else {
            console.log("Successfully saved new news");
            res.send(result);
          }
        });
      } else {
        console.log("No category found for ::", req.body.category);
        res.send("No category found");
      }
    }
  );
});
```

index.js

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "10mb", extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "10mb" }));
```

HTML:

```
                <form fxLayout="row wrap" [formGroup]="createNewsForm" (ngSubmit)="createNews()"
                    enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-sm="100" class="px-1" ngClass.sm="mt-1" ngClass.xs="mt-1">
                        <label>Title</label>
                        <mat-form-field class="w-100 form-group">
                            <input type="text" matInput placeholder="Article title (required)"
                                formControlName="articleTitle" name="articleTitle" required>
                            <mat-error *ngIf="articleTitle?.invalid">Please enter a valid Title</mat-error>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                    <div fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-sm="100" class="px-1" ngClass.sm="mt-1" ngClass.xs="mt-1">
                        <label>Category</label>
                        <mat-form-field class="w-100 form-group">
                            <select matNativeControl formControlName="articleCategory" name="articleCategory"
                                color="accent">
                                <option *ngFor="let category of categories" [value]="category.categoryId">
                                    {{category.categorySlug}}</option>
                            </select>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                    <div class="button-wrap" fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-sm="100" class="px-1" ngClass.sm="mt-1"
                        ngClass.xs="mt-1">
                        <button class="btn-project" mat-raised-button color="accent" type="submit">Post News</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

component.ts

```
createNewsForm: FormGroup;

ngOnInIt() {
this.createNewsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      articleTitle: ['', Validators.required],
      articleCategory: ['', Validators.required],
      imagePath: ['', Validators.required]
    })
}

public createNews: any = () => {

    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('imagePath', this.createNewsForm.get('imagePath').value);
    formData.append('title', this.createNewsForm.get('articleTitle').value);
    formData.append('category', this.createNewsForm.get('articleCategory').value);
this.appService.createNews(formData).subscribe(

      data => {
        console.log(data)
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }
```

appService.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

  public createNews = (formData) => {

    let myResponse = this.http.post(this.baseUrl + '/api/v1/post-news', formData);
    return myResponse;
  }
```

Comment: And how are you calling this route from Angular?

Comment: I'm appending everything as formData.append() and sending them as form-data as a post request like this.http.post(this.baseUrl + '/api/v1/post-news', formData);

Comment: Please add the relevant front-end code to the question.

Comment: sure I'm doing it in just a sec, but just to let you know, irrespective of the frontend, when I even do a post request from postman and send the data as form-data, req.body.category is coming as undefined

Comment: Yes so I'm interested in _how_ you send the request. You're not saying how, so we can't tell why :)

Comment: @JeremyThille got ya! updated! check now

Comment: like @eol said, I believe `body-parser` is trying to parse the body as JSON, but it's not. It's form data. You need the proper parser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an appropriate parser to handle *multipart/form-data* (this is what the content-type will be set to after selecting "form-data" in postman), the built in bodyParsers(urlencoded/json) do not handle it. One popular package you can use is [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer).

They provide an `upload`-middleware that you can plug into your route handler, e.g.:

```
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

app.post(`${baseUrl}/post-news`, upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
   // req.file will now hold the uploaded file
   // req.body will hold the text fields of the form
});
```